# Using LIKE command in MySQL giving weird results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL, but have used Access for many years in intranet development. Recently started using a MySQL database and pulling my hair out. The LIKE command is giving erratic or no results for records that do exist.

A table called "Clients", containing a column called "BusinessName". One record is for example "FRED SMITH CONSTRUCTIONS".

```sql
Select * from Clients where BusinessName LIKE '%FRED%' -- returns true.
Select * from Clients where BusinessName LIKE '%FRED SMITH%' -- returns false!
Select * from Clients where BusinessName LIKE '%FRED%SMITH%' -- returns false!
Select * from Clients where BusinessName LIKE '%FRED%S%' -- returns true.
Select * from Clients where BusinessName LIKE '%FRED%SM%' -- returns false!
Select * from Clients where BusinessName LIKE '%FRED%S%C%' -- returns true.
```

Its pretty erratic, and makes no sense to me at all. Any more than 1 word and it seams to get confused. Its like the % wildcard doesn't work between words, or if there is more than one character in the 2nd word.

To get me out of trouble I'm searching for each word separately, but this shows too many results. eg

```sql
Select * from Clients where BusinessName LIKE '%FRED%' or BusinessName LIKE '%SMITH%'
```

returns true.

Any suggestions? The column type is Text. Tried `RLIKE` with similar results.

Comment: I'd say your first problem is using the `TEXT` type. This is a CLOB type. Switch to `VARCHAR` and your problem will probably go away

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing the same results in this demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd9de/3

Comment: Check your data carefully. The problem is there.

Comment: I'm guessing that one of your spaces is not really a space (or not a single one).

Comment: Have you looked into MATCH AGAINST? You will need full text index on the searched field

Comment: Changing to Varchar made no difference. Data is OK, even manually entered some records to test with, no hidden characters. % should cover multiple spaces. This has got me stumped. Weird thing is I see same problem both on the development server ( win ) and live server ( Linux ). There are 19,000 records, wondering if its timing out on complex searches and just returning false instead of continuing?

Comment: Yeah tried MATCH AGAINST too, same results.

Comment: Just adding, using ODBC to connect to the database, though don't think that's a factor.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you, insert a record just like what your searching, only use your keyboard and no copy/paste, the try again, if it works correct, your keyoard codepage differs from the one in database

Comment: Yeah didn't help. In fact this database is returning absolute rubbish now. Manually entered "RONALD GLENN", and it couldn't find RONALD, but could find ONALD!

Comment: Search for RON returned true, RONA returned false. R GLE returned true, R GLEN returned false. About to give up on this. Note using % wildcard in spaces and around outside.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Could you create table by doing [create..select into..](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html) and then executing the same queries on both the original and the newly-created tables?

Comment: I created a new table and imported some of the records from the Clients table, and the LIKE command works correctly. Go figure. Imported the rest of the rows, deleted the old table and renamed the new to Clients, and it now works perfectly. Must have been some weirdness in the old table. Thanks for the replies and suggestions, if nothing else I did learn a lot about LIKE, RLIKE and wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Your column character set is probably not what you expect.  MySQL installations frequently default to something other than ISO8859-1.